# How to read current MIDI status for AKAI MIDIMIX?

Tags: midi, midi-interface

As per [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660770/how-to-get-a-current-state-of-a-midi-device) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56093682/how-to-force-a-midi-device-to-report-control-status) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735414/how-to-read-the-initial-state-of-a-midi-foot-controller), there is no standard way to force a MIDI controller to send the current state of its sliders and knobs. However, all answers points to the possible existence of manufacturer-specific SysEx command to do so.

Is there such a SysEx command for the [AKAI MIDIMIX](https://www.akaipro.com/midimix) controller?

Comment: If the manual does not tell you about those commands, ask Akai, or reverse engineer the editor application.

Comment: @CL. The editor application is extremely minimalistic and doesn't even display status when it's updated by the controller. The manual is, well, close to empty. I've asked Akai support. If I ever get a good answer, I'll post it here.